# Cohomology calculation or computation?

Tags: terminology, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

I have a terminology question:

Does one *compute* the cohomology of a group, or does one *calculate* it?

Is it more common to speak of cohomology calculation or cohomology computation?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In my experience, one usually computes, but I'm sure that if you said 'calculate' everyone would know what you meant, and nobody would think it sounded weird.

Comment: "Compute", "calculate", "find", "determine" -- these, and anything else synonymous, are perfectly acceptable. It isn't a technical term.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer!